# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while trying to use python swampy

Tags: python, swampy

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
import random

world = TurtleWorld()
Turtle_1 = Turtle()

print('*****Welcome to Sehir Minesweeper*****')
print('-----First Turtle-----')

Turtle_1 = input('Please type the name of the first Turtle:')

print('Turtle 1 is' +' ' + Turtle_1)

T1_color = input('Please choose turtle color for' + ' ' + Turtle_1 +' '+'(red, blue or green):')

Turtle_1.color(T1_color)
```

Comment: At first glance it might seem like all the stuff nagging you about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is really annoying, but actually it's trying to help you get answers. If you tell us what you're expecting, what's going wrong, whether you have any error messages, what research you've done etc you're much more likely to get an answer than you are by posting a block of code with no context. Really, it's in your best interests, so people feel like helping you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `Turtle_1` as a `Turtle` object, which is correct. Then, however, with the line `Turtle_1 = input('Please...')`, you set `Turtle_1` to a string, as `input()` returns a string. When you then attempted to call the `color()` method, this did not work, as strings have no such method. In addition, Turtles also have the `set_color()` method for setting the color, and `color` is an attribute and cannot be called.

Comment: how can i fix that i want the player to name the turtle but i need it to be a turtle aswell :D

Comment: I would use another variable called something like T1_name and then just use `T1_name = input('Please type the name of the first Turtle: ')`. Then you would also want to replace `Turtle_1.color(T1_color)` with `Turtle_1.set_color(T1_color)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to call a string. The error that results is `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

```
Turtle_1.color(T1_color)
```

`color` is a string property of `Turtle`. To set the color, use:

```
Turtle_1.set_color(T1_color)
```

Which is the same as:

```
Turtle_1.color = T1_color
Turtle_1.redraw()
```